# Time picker in android

Tags: android

HI Every One. I am new to android Developmemt . Actually my project requires to show Timepicker but i doesnot want to show AM or PM option and also not in the header of the picker, There is any way to do this ?
Please reply ASAP

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the AM/PM selector using the `setIs24HourView(true)` method of `TimePicker`. I've not tried it myself, but I think this should also remove the AM/PM caption from the header.
Hope that helps, bye